# mysql query with multiple group by's

Tags: mysql

i am trying to write an SQL query but this is a bit to complicated for me.

I have a table with these fields:

```
user1, user2, user1Payed, user2Payed.
```

`user1` and `user2` have emails inside.
`user1Payed` and `user2Payed` have numbers inside, representing a kind of payments.

This is a table that represents all the orders users have made.
`user1` and `user1Payed` are bound by meaning.
`user2` and `user2Payed` are also bound by meaning.
orders in my system are made by 2 users that do not have to be distinct. this means that an order could be made be the same user. in this case it could be that `user1Payed` and `user2Payed` would have different values.

my goal is to write a query that will calculate all distinct users that have a total of `userPayed` (`user1Payed` + `user2Payed`) over a certain number. this means that i need to count the amount of all `user1Payed` and `user2Payed` associated with a distinct user.

i understand that some use of `GROUP BY` should be made here but this is insufficient because this will not address all posibilities.

take for an example the case the in a specific row my `user1` and `user2` are the same username, how will i calculate `user1Payed` and `user2Payed`?

It seems that what i should do is make a table with all the rows that a certain user is `user1` and then check its `user1Payed`.
then make another table with all the rows that the user is `user2` and count `user2Payed`.
after this i need to sum up the 2 results and from this result i could make the final result.

but i don't have any idea how would i implement this.

thanks alot.

Comment: Post some sample data with the desired result,it would have been a lot simpler than the above telenovela.

Comment: The past participle of "pay" is "paid" in English, not "payed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UNION` to combine the data for each user column.

```
SELECT user, SUM(amount) total
FROM (
    SELECT user1 user, user1Payed amount
    FROM table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user2 user, user2Payed amount
    FROM table
) u
GROUP BY user
```

I don't know what "bound by meaning" means, I hope it isn't relevant to the answer.